# remotely installing python and pip packages

Tags: powershell, azure, python, deployment, pip

I'm trying to install python with pip packages remotely on an Azure VM using powershell. The script deployed to the VM:

```
Start-Process 'F:\python-3.9.5-amd64.exe'-ArgumentList ("/passive", "InstallAllUsers=1", "PrependPath=1", "Include_test=0", "Include_pip=1") -Wait
Start-Sleep -s 120
& pip install urllib3 --no-index --find-links 'F:\urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
& pip install selenium --no-index --find-links 'F:\selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

Python is installed correctly in Program Files, and environment variables are added, but `pip` is not recognised.

I've tried setting an environment variable in the script (`set` / `setx` ..) for both the Python and the Scripts folders, but it didn't help. If I RDP on to the machine `pip` is recognised, and the packages are installed correctly. `python` is not recognised either (tried `python -m pip install ...`).

Why is pip not recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script executes the install but does not refresh the environment between the install and the execution of `pip`. Consequently, `pip` executable cannot be found in path.

To retrieve the value of `$env:PATH` and add a custom path

```
$scriptblock = { 
    $env:computername
    [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
    # add pip path to $env:path variable temporarily
    $env:path += ";c:\whatever\pip"
    # run pip here
    python -m pip install package 
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Note that [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) may be a better way to install software; it also offers a `refreshenv` command to reload the environment variables.